# Getting around automatic initializer inheritance rules Swift

Tags: swift, inheritance, initialization

I have a set of classes that all inherit from one superclass. This superclass provides an initializer that is generic enough to be suitable for all the subclasses. Specifically it contains:

```
init(values: [String: Any]) {
    updateValues(dict: values)
}
```

and

```
func updateValues(dict: [String: Any]){
    //To be implemented in subclasses
}
```

By overriding `updateValues()` in the subclasses, and by utilizing dynamic dispatch to ensure that each subclass correctly sets its own variables, everything seems to work.

For example, in a user class, properties are declared like so:

```
var name: String?
var uid: String?
var email: String?
var username: String?
```

and its `updateValues()` looks like:

```
override func updateValues(dict: [String: Any]) {
    self.name = dict["name"] as? String
    self.uid = dict["uid"] as? String
    self.email = dict["email"] as? String
    self.username = dict["username"] as? String
}
```

This works perfectly. But I need to add custom designated initializers to the subclass in cases where the variables need to be set manually, as opposed to from a dictionary. For example, one such initializer for the above mentioned user class would be:

```
init(name: String?, uid: String?, email: String?, username: String?){...
```

Yet this initializer declaration produces an undesired result. As per the Swift "Automatic Initializer Inheritance" rules on [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) page, once one designated initializer is provided to the subclass, it no longer inherits the initializers of the superclass. This makes inheritance quite tedious, as I now must override the initializer I want to automatically inherit, and simply call `super.init()` for every subclass. I must also rewrite the comments for every instance of this `override init` -- `super.init()` workaround.

Is there anyway to still inherit the superclass designated initializers? Or am I thinking about this incorrectly?

Note: I commented out the designated initializers of the subclass and the superclass initializers were automatically inherited. There really is no change in functionality by adding additional subclass initializers (or uncommenting them,) so I'd like to find a way to work around the safety check Swift enforces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should (and must) always call a designated initializer. That's what it means to be the designated initializer. If your designated initializer is `init(value:)`, then `init(name: String?, uid: String?, email: String?, username: String?)` should be a convenience initializer that calls it. Implementing a new "must-call" (i.e. designated initializer) means that the superclass's designated initializer is invalid for this subclass, but that's not the case here. So just write:

```
convenience init(name: String?, uid: String?, email: String?, username: String?) {
    self.init(values: ["name": name, "uid": uid, "email": email, "username": username])
}
```

This shouldn't invalidate your other inits.